# Angular DataTables - Cannot read property 'match'

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am working with jQuery and Angular Datatables. I am not getting data in table.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined at Object.i [as render] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)

These are plugins I arranged like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

This is my Table in jsp file: all internships saved in database has to view in table. Is jquery table good to use with angularjs?

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody ng-repeat="internship in deatilInternships[0]">
        <tr>
            <td><span>{{$index+1}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.title}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.category.name}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.status}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{internship.appliedDate |
                        date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Hold" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="hold(internship.id)"> <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>

                </button> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="update(internship.id)">
                                                                                                <i class="icon bb-edit"></i></a>

                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="deleteinternship(internship.id)"> <i class="icon bb-trash"></i>

                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-title="View" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="viewInternship(internship.id)"> <i class="icon bb-view"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and data is coming form backend.

controller.js:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(10);

var getInternships = function () {
    var data = "pageNumber=" + pageNumber + "&pageSize=" + $scope.pageSize;
    internshipService.getInternships(data, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $scope.internshipsLength = data.length;
        }
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            if (latestinterships.length == 0) {
                latestinterships = data;
            } else if (latestinterships.length > 0) {
                latestinterships = latestinterships.concat(data);
            }
            $scope.deatilInternships = [];
            var index = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < latestinterships.length; i++) {
                if (!$scope.deatilInternships[index]) {
                    $scope.deatilInternships[index] = [];
                }
                $scope.deatilInternships[index].push(latestinterships[i]);
            }
        }
        $rootScope.InternshipCount = data.length;
    });
};
getInternships();
```

app.js: I injected dependency also as 'datatables'

Nothing is displaying in the table.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Object.i [as render] (angular-datatables.min.js:6) Getting this error

Comment: hopefully your real code is not `$rootScope.InternshipCount = d ata.length;`

Comment: @davidkonrad, that's my mistake while correcting the formatting. I think `ng-repeat` should be in `tr` not in `tbody`.

Comment: @davidkonrad, yes OP is just loading.