# Iteration in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on angular js with python flask and I'm facing one challenge to iterate through JSON in one scenario. The scenario is as below:
JSON is:

```
{
    "categories": ["ladies", "men", "kids", "home", "sale", "life"],
    "home": [{
        "categories": "New Arrivals",
        "categoryTitle": "home"
    }],
    "kids": [{
        "categories": "New Arrivals",
        "categoryTitle": "Baby"
    }],
    "men": [...multiple nodes...],
    "ladies": [...multiple nodes...]
}
```

I want to print data from categories json e.g. kids.categoryTitle but my category names are coming dynamically from categories list in the same json.

What I'm trying to print is:

```
<div ng-repeat="catName in ctrl.tableData.cats"><tr data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in ctrl.tableData.catName"></tr></div>
```

But the above code is not working where as if I use `ctrl.tableData.kids1 instead of`ctrl.tableData.catName1 it works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is `cats` data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of your data, which read category name from object, then load that key's data and loop over them

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    categories: ["ladies", "men", "kids", "home", "sale", "life"],
    home: [{
      categories: "New Arrivals",
      categoryTitle: "home"
    }],
    kids: [{
      categories: "New Arrivals",
      categoryTitle: "Baby"
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="d in data.categories">
    Category: {{d}}
    <br>
    Data:
    <li data-ng-repeat="k in data[d]">
      {{k}}
    </li>

    <hr>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

***!*** do not put `tr` tag inside `div` tag

Also your JSON does not have `cats` data.

---

**Update**

Making multiple tables from your data

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    categories: ["kids", "home"],
    home: [{
      categories: "home 1.1",
      categoryTitle: " home1.2"
    }, {
      categories: "home 2.1",
      categoryTitle: "home 2.2"
    }, {
      categories: "home 3.1",
      categoryTitle: "home 3.2"
    }, {
      categories: "home 4.1",
      categoryTitle: "home 4.2"
    }, {
      categories: "home 5.1",
      categoryTitle: "home 5.2"
    }],
    kids: [{
      categories: "kids 1.1",
      categoryTitle: "kids 1.2"
    }]
  };


  $scope.getKeys = function(obj) {
    if (!$scope.data.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys($scope.data[obj][0]);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table ng-repeat="d in data.categories">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="l in x = getKeys(d)" ng-if="l!= '$$hashKey'">
        {{l}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="k in data[d]">
      <td>{{k.categories}}</td>
      <td>{{k.categoryTitle}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Update 2**

Using a table with multiple `tbody`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    categories: ["kids", "home"],
    home: [{
        categories: "home 1.1",
        categoryTitle: " home1.2"
      },
      {
        categories: "home 2.1",
        categoryTitle: "home 2.2"
      },
      {
        categories: "home 3.1",
        categoryTitle: "home 3.2"
      },
      {
        categories: "home 4.1",
        categoryTitle: "home 4.2"
      },
      {
        categories: "home 5.1",
        categoryTitle: "home 5.2"
      }
    ],
    kids: [{
      categories: "kids 1.1",
      categoryTitle: "kids 1.2"
    }]
  };

  $scope.getKeys = function(obj) {
    if (!$scope.data.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys($scope.data[obj][0]);
  };
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="d in data.categories">
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="l in x = getKeys(d)" ng-if="l!= '$$hashKey'">
          {{l}}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="k in data[d]">
        <td>{{k.categories}}</td>
        <td>{{k.categoryTitle}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello Saeed, Thanks for your response. Actually I've re checked and its working if I use it like <div ng-repeat="catName in ctrl.tableData.cats"><tr data-ng-repeat="(key, data) in ctrl.tableData[catName]"></tr></div>  But the real issue is as you mentioned I'm putting tr inside div, that is the reason why its' not printing the data. Now my concern is little changed here, how Can i print data within a table with nested ng-repeat, I went through lots of forums and gave a try like ng-repat of <tbody> but doesn't help, I'm working with angular datatables hence can't really avoid tables

Comment: several tables for each category item?? @Jitender

Comment: Hi Saeed, Thanks you very much for your response again, I really appreciate. This is really working what I was expecting. Now one small issue it will print multiple tables for all the categories where as I'm expecting result to be in single table. I've tried main loop on tbody instead of table but its throwing exception TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. It will really be great if you can suggest further solution to it.  Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: I add an update for `one table, multiple tbody`. It works well. But your error is not related to this. You used `match` for an undefined variable. log the variable before using `match` of it. Or provide a codepen or plunker for me to help. @Jitender

Comment: Hi Saeed, meanwhile I create a plunker please go through the following link, I'm exactly facing the same issue if I put ng-repeat on tbody.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866738/angular-datatables-cannot-read-property-match

Comment: Hi Saeed, Please refer the below plunker which  is a working example of datatable, just change the location of ng-repeat from tr to tbody and you can see the error in browser console. http://plnkr.co/edit/72IDOSixbpb4gl8fwhvR?p=preview .          actually I've checked that this is not the issue of ng-repeat on tbody but issue of the angular datatable plugin that I've used here, this particular datatable plugin is not supporting iteration on tbody.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, As they said [here](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/243) It does not support it. Create table with other structure. Good luck. @Jitender